# Placing Text in UITextField

Tags: iphone, xcode, text, uitextfield, position

```
textField.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGreenColorTransparent].CGColor;
textField.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
textField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
```

How can I set the text for about `5px` to the right that there is more space between the border and the beginning of the text?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];         
> textField.leftView = paddingView;
> textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
> ```

set the leftView property for padding the UITextField.

Answer (score 1):

**drawTextInRect:**
Draws the receiver’s text in the specified rectangle.

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

**Parameters**
*rect*
The rectangle in which to draw the text.
**Discussion**
You should not call this method directly. If you want to customize the drawing behavior for the text, you can override this method to do your drawing.

By the time this method is called, the current graphics context is already configured with the default environment and text color for drawing. In your overridden method, you can configure the current context further and then invoke super to do the actual drawing or you can do the drawing yourself. If you do render the text yourself, you should not invoke super.

**Availability**
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
**Declared In**
UITextField.h

Answer (score 1):

```
 textField.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4,8,0,0);
```

Comment: Does not work. Xcode does not find this method. Did you mean `Content Mode`?